# Cost of creation of boost::file_mapping object?

Tags: c++, performance, boost, ipc, filemap

I have a file parser, which loads the file as a file mapping object and then maps region based on the caller's demand.
The files can be accessed locally or from over the network.

This file reading is sequential.

I have had 2 approaches -

> **Approach 1**
>
> Create a file_mapping object, say f.
>
> Create mapped regions using
>   'f', where at a time, only one mapped_region is active.
>
> **Approach 2**
>
> *Create new file_mapping object(for the same file), every time a
>   mapped_region is to be created.*

Approach 2 based on the assumption that file_mapping are designed for Inter Process Communication, so creating multiple file_mapping objects for the same file will not be an issue.

> When the file was accessed locally, the performance benchmarks, shown,
>   similar timings in both the approaches(for a 3GB File)
>
> However, when the files were being accessed from over the network,
>   Approach 2, performed *~5 times slower* as compared to Approach 1.

In both the approaches, the mapped_region is getting destructed, before a new one gets created.

The only difference in Approach 2 is that file_mapping object gets created and destructed for each mapped_region.

> > **Bench marking Procedure for sequential file read operation:**
> >     -File Size : 3GB
> >     -Number of Mapped Regions Created : 8600
> >     -Mapped Region Size : Variable, varies in the range of 9KB - 900KB
> >     -Mapped Region Access : All the regions are accessed immediately after their
> >     creation.
> >     -Mapped Region Creation Frequency : One after the other in
> >     loop, with some processing of the data extracted from mapped region.
> >     The processing involves recursive structure population, though depth is max
> >     10. It is not very intensive.

I want to understand:

> > Why is there such a huge difference in timings?
> >
> > What exactly happens when a file_mapping object is created?
> >
> > What exactly happens when a mapped_region objected is created?
> >
> > Does the OS searches for a big chunk of memory during file_mapping
> >     creation or during mapped_region creation?
> >
> > When is the file data actually loaded in main memory?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer this question without knowing your benchmark procedure, i.e. how often you created the `mapped_region` objects, how big were the mapped portions, and which fractions of them were actually accessed.

It's also unclear if in your implementation the file mapping object (`boost::file_mapping`) also opens the file handle explicitly, or the file is opened by you.

I can only guess that creating the file and mapping object in network file system probably requires more inter-PC communication (for synchronization).

Comment: I will add these details in my question

Comment: The file_mapping object opens the file handle. I do not open the file through any other call.